# How can I fix this Pokemon GO spinning Pokéstops problem?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a problem with Pokemon GO: I can catch Pokemon but when trying to spin Pokéstops it keeps saying `try again later`. What can I do to fix this? What went wrong?

Comment: I sometimes see this when I try to spin it immediately after it becomes available again (changes from purple back to blue). Check your journal, you may have gotten it.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question. The phenomenon described is one that occurs frequently, even when the rest of the game is working perfectly. Reopen, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I find that I experience this if I try spinning a Pokéstop too quickly after clicking it. This is especially true when the Pokéstop image hasn't loaded yet.

Try waiting longer before you spin the Pokéstop. Even if you get stuck with *Try again later.*, you should be able to just wait 5 minutes and spin it.